# How to remove forward slashes from file in unix shell using sed?

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed

I have the following file :

```
/
/FUSE
//
Bank S.A / N.V
/F
```

I want to remove *all* forward slashes (`/`), so that the result looks like this:

```
FUSE

Bank S.A  N.V
F
```

How to do so using `sed`? Ive tried using `tr`, but `tr` is not what I need, because I want to edit the file in-place without printing it to console.

Comment: You appear to have deleted the last line in the example output. Is that a requirement of any solution here too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different separator than `/` into the `sed` expression, for example `:`:

```
sed 's:/::g' file
```

to remove all `/` irrespective of where they are on the line.

If you want to replace the existing file, use `-i`, meaning "inplace", which can be followed by an extension to backup the old file, for example this will keep a copy of the old file named `file.old` and modify `file`:

```
sed -i.old 's:/::g' file
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tr` for this:

```
$ tr -d '/' < file

FUSE

Bank S.A  N.V
F
```

To save the output, just redirect to a new file:

```
tr -d '/' < file > file.fixed
```

Comment: An advantage of `tr` is that it works even for non-text files, while YMMV for `sed` (depending on the `sed` implementation).

Comment: Note that `/` is not (thanfully!) special to the shell; it doesn't need to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sed this way:

`sed --in-place 's/\///g' file`

You just ask `sed` to substitute (s) pattern / with void space.